# Whats is DB Connections(Count) in AWS?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, rds, dbconnection

What is meaning of DB Connections(Count) report on AWS RDS? 
I have gone through their documentation but didn't find my answer there.

I am quite confused with **DB Connection report** on my AWS. I can see their only 1 connection available but I am sure that there are always 100-150 concurrent users on my website on different pages which users database operation.

As the user concurrency is 100-150 then why it shows me only 1 connection on report.

Note : My website is working well on good performance.
[image]

Comment: Question your premises: Does a single user on your web application *necessarily* equate to a single database connection? Should you be using the 'Sum' statistic instead of 'Maximum'? Is it reasonable that, at any given instant that this 1-minute sampling would occur, that only 1 or 2 connections would be open?  Have you accounted for things like connection pooling?

Answer (score 6):

The database connection count [is exactly what it sounds like](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/rds-metricscollected.html): "The number of database connections in use."

It's a count, so it shouldn't be summed. Maximum or averaging are recommended. It may be registering low because you have a very efficient database pool, have server-level caching, or are looking at the wrong database in your statistics.

Comment: If I changed the Metric to "Sum" than , Should it given me total number of active connection in use ?

Comment: No, it'll give you the number of connections in use multiplied by the number of samplings in the given time period.